# string.length devuelve undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un input de texto en html el cual sirve para introducir nombres. Al recoger el texto desde javascript, si que me deja mostrarlo por pantalla pero si intento mostrar la longitud de la cadena, me devuelve undefined. ¿A que se puede deber esto?
También lo he intentado con nombrePersona.lenght pero sigue sin funcionar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, el código y otra información relevante (mensajes de error, etc) ha de mostrarse **como texto**. Las imágenes no se pueden copiar/pegar para buscar o hacer pruebas. Te has pasado por [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: Se escribe **`length`**

Answer (score -1):

El error es que estas escribiendo lenght siendo lo correcto **length**

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");

boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var input = document.getElementById("texto").value;

  alert("numero de caracteres: " + input.length);
});
```

```html
    <input type="text"  id="texto">

    <button id="boton">Obtner valor</button>
```